# IWebViewControl for localhost

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, webview, windows-runtime

I'm trying out a c++ sample to run IWebViewControl in a Win32 Window, see
[Win32WebView](https://github.com/fobrs/WebViewSample.Win32.cppwinrt).

I can display external websites just fine, but cannot connect to http://localhost (or http://127.0.0.1). Using the standalone Edge browser displays the page from localhost. Is this a limitation of the IWebViewControl or did I overlook something?

Comment: So are you running a web-server at your localhost? Also don't provide links to code (for whatever external code hosting service), but provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: Yes, I run a web-server at localhost. No chance for me to post minimal code on how to run an WebViewControl. Would be hundreds of lines.

Comment: My google-fu revealed [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2226). Does it help?

Comment: Cannot connect - why? What error do you get?

Comment: @zett42, oh this looks like the solution. Will chech it out and report the result here. Thanks :-)

Comment: If it works, you should [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zett42 pointed me in the right direction:

WinRT applications operate in a sandbox and for security reasons it is not allowed to connect to localhost. This can be circumvented by using the tool

checknetisolation.exe

which is shipped with Windows. In case of the IWebViewControl you can lift the restriction for the IWebViewControl host process for development purposes by

checknetisolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy